# Update range of cells in excel only its value is "0" based on a condition using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say i have cell-"A1" with value "abc".

I have range "B1:G1" with cell values either "0" or "1".
When the value in the cell "A1" changes to "def" only the cells having "0" from range "B1:G1" should change to "2".

Can i achieve the above scenario only by using excel formula?

Thanks,
Prasanna M

Comment: Are the values in `B1:G1` constants or formulas on their own?

Comment: I won't submit this as the answer due to the unknowns in question and as @JvdV has pointed out, however you may find this useful to copy into `B1:G1`: `=IF($A$1="abc",0,IF($A$1="def",2,""))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Hi @JvdV, assume the values in B1:G1 is constants without any formula

Comment: This could get confusing. You ask in the above scenario if its possible by formula alone, yet the values in the cells are constants. In that case ***no***, it's not possible to change constants with a formula in another cell. You'd need VBA.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @Mech, The formula you have mentioned will change all the cell values to either "0" or "2" based on the condition. But what i need is, it should change only cells from "B1:G1" having "0"s and not "1"s.

Comment: what are the `0` and `1` values based on?

Comment: Yes,I thought so i need VBA @JvdV. To simply put i need formula for "B1:G1" to update its cell value based on its own cell value and "A1". But this will create circular dependency. I thought there will be some other way to workaround this problem. Anyways thanks.